# Sealing of hatches of Spacecraft capsule, LM and spacesuits

Tags: spacesuits, hatch

Was there any "plan B" / solution, in case sealing of capsule hatch, LM hatch and spacesuit helmet failed during Apollo missions or any other spacecraft? How did NASA ensure a failproof sealing in all these cases?

Comment: Are you asking for the plan if all 3 seals failed simultaneously?

Comment: "What happens if X redundant systems fail, couldn't they use X+1 systems?" No matter how big X is, you can always ask an X+1 question. At some point you have to accept the remaining risk and move on. That is true not only for aerospace, but life in general.

Comment: @Organic Marble - No. (Also @ Polygnome has correctly said, X+1  will always exist, no matter how big X is.) Not all at the same time, but any one at a given time would be fatal. Basically looking for the concept of sealing which was / is being treated as fairly dependable. Which means I am also willing to accept X =1. Just want to know "how" of that X..

Comment: "Any one" would not be fatal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are so many questions here that I will answer only a few of them**.  If anyone wants to edit/update please feel free.

Let us take a look at a hypothetical Apollo mission in which one of these systems fails at a time, not all three.  The answer to the question 'what happens if a hatch fails to close AND a helmet fails to close' on the moon is "you die".  However, there were procedures for what happens if one of those two things fail on the moon.

**Excessive Cabin Leak**: In the LM operations document [Found here](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/LM11HandbookVol2.pdf), the assumption made is that the crew is wearing helmets/gloves at all times.  In the case of an excessive cabin air leak, regardless of whether it is from the hatch not closing properly or what caused it, a sequence of events happens that basically involve the cabin repressurization system to kick in and the astronauts to use their suits until the issue passes (see below)

**Helmet won't close in a depressurized cabin**: This is covered under the "suit leak in depressurized cabin" portion of the document I linked, since the astronauts would obviously never have their helmets *open* in a depressurized cabin, the only chance of this happening would be if the helmet seal came undone or something else caused a link.  The procedure is for the astronaut without the leak to seal the hatch and repressurize the cabin immediately.

if by some chance the suit leak happened in a depressurized cabin AND it was excessive enough to require emergency procedures to repressurize the cabin AND the cabin could not be repressurized then the astronaut would die...

Comment: Thanks Michael Stachowsky.. Precise response. Hope the "sealing arrangement" is also described in these manuals. Just in case they are not, can you suggest some link where I can find the same?

Comment: Further, What if the helmet opened / leaked while on an EVA... Of course, the astronaut will die. I am sure NASA would have given enough thought to this. What were the sealing methods which were perceived and proved to be fairly dependable?